# .net create custom request and response for web service?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, web-services

I am doing an integration where I have to consume 3rd party java based web service.
This 3rd party web service is highly case sensitive.
After adding the web service to the .net project.
We called there methods. But .net code creates its own Request XML which is different then the XML needed by the vendor.

For example .net creates XML as Follows

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <GetAccountBalanceRequest xmlns="http://www.XXXXXXX.com/lmsglobal/ws/v1/extint/types">
        <Authentication>
            <Principal xmlns="http://www.XXXXXXX.com/lmsglobal/xsd/v1/types">
                <PrincipalValue>9401120106480306</PrincipalValue>
                <PrincipalClassifier>0001</PrincipalClassifier>
            </Principal>
            <Credential xmlns="http://www.XXXXXXX.com/lmsglobal/xsd/v1/types"/>
        </Authentication>
        <LoyaltyCurrency xsi:nil="true"/>
    </GetAccountBalanceRequest>
</s:Body>
```

But the vendor say they want XML as Follows

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:typ="http://www.XXXXXXX.com/lmsglobal/ws/v1/extint/types" xmlns:typ1="http://www.XXXXXXX.com/lmsglobal/xsd/v1/types">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <typ:GetAccountBalanceRequest>
         <typ:Authentication>
            <typ1:Principal>
               <typ1:PrincipalValue>9401120106480306</typ1:PrincipalValue>
               <typ1:PrincipalClassifier>0001</typ1:PrincipalClassifier>
            </typ1:Principal>
         </typ:Authentication>
      </typ:GetAccountBalanceRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

How do I modify the web service so it will generate Request XML as vender needs?

I used Soap UI also for checking the response. If I use .net generated XML then it fails but I use the above XML then it works.

Comment: What is the difference between those 2 XMLs?

Comment: I don't see one either.

Comment: I think you made a mistake, my WCF runs fine with Java and I didn't had the problem of having 2 different kind of XML. Make sure your connection with the WSDL is fine.

Comment: sorry, I can't seem to find the difference between the two xml segments. can you specify exactly which line(s) display the difference?

Comment: Sorry I posted the wrong XML. My bad.